# Medicines in the fridge

Tags: medicinal-chemistry

Why are there some medicines that are put in the fridge?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should ask yourself why we use fridges _at all_.

Answer (score 1):

some medicines contain unstable compounds, which will react with their environment and could cause them to degrade before they have a chance to be taken. chemical reactions require energy to occur, so by reducing the thermal energy available to these compounds, they will react slower

so basically, making things colder means reactions happen slower and your medicine keeps longer